# How to compare the date stored in mongodb with present date?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to compare the date stored in a *MongoDB* document with the present date and find out if there is a minimum 15 days difference.

The date field in the *MongoDB* schema is like:

```
{type: Date, default: Date.now()}
```

Comment: Are you comparing it in the query (e.g. select all posts older than some date), or are you doing it in javascript afterwards?

Comment: injavascript in app.get() method